# Desktop compositing issues with gtx 690 and Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, opengl

I'm having a bit of trouble with Kubuntu 14.04 on my desktop. I have a GTX 690 with the Nvidia 331 drivers installed (through the driver manager).

Whenever I boot into Kubuntu, I'm met with terrible screen tearing artifacts when moving windows. Forcing full-screen repaints does not fix the problem. When I go to look at the desktop render settings, they are by default set to OpenGL 2.0. Changing to a different OpenGL version immediately fixes the problem. However, after rebooting, the same problem exists, and I must go into the settings and change the OpenGL version to something different again. And curiously enough, changing to a different OpenGL version, then changing back, fixes the problem as well.

I should note that this problem does not happen with the same OS on my laptop with Intel HD Graphics, and that other UIs/compositing managers do not show this problem on my desktop with the same drivers, so I think it's unique to KDE.

I was wondering if anybody knew of a way to fix this problem once and for all, so I don't have to keep changing the OpenGL version each boot. Or at the very least, create a script that would perform this task at boot automatically.

Comment: Seems like not a single person knows how to fix this issue -.-